# i want to output on 404 page the url the user was trying to use that resulted in the 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-referer, custom-error-pages, redirect

I'm trying to create a custom 404 page to include this information:

> Sorry, this page was not found
>
> The page you was trying to view was:
>
> Please check the URL is spelt correctly, if it is then this page may
>   have been moved, removed or never existed

I have tried using: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to capture the URL that the user was trying to view before they got automatically redirected to the 404 page

working .htaccess code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

It's working now, thanks everyone who helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which gives you the URI which was given to access the current page.  The result is in format `/request_uri.php`.  Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for further details.

In your `404.php` you could do the following:

```
The page you were trying to view was: <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

**Update:**

Update your `ErrorDocument` declaration as follows:

```
# Remove http://www.example.com
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

From the docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)

> Note that when you specify an ErrorDocument that points to a remote URL (ie. anything with a method such as http in front of it), Apache will send a redirect to the client to tell it where to find the document, even if the document ends up being on the same server. This has several implications, the most important being that the client will not receive the original error status code, but instead will receive a redirect status code. This in turn can confuse web robots and other clients which try to determine if a URL is valid using the status code. In addition, if you use a remote URL in an ErrorDocument 401, the client will not know to prompt the user for a password since it will not receive the 401 status code. Therefore, if you use an ErrorDocument 401 directive then it must refer to a local document.

Comment: it shows: The page you were trying to view was: /404  when it show be /cats

Comment: @JenStar23, please update your ErrorDocument definition as `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`.  I've updated my answer to include as to why.

Comment: @JenStar23, check for any typos or syntax errors, you shouldn't be getting 500 just for changing that line.

Comment: added same more of .htaccess above, incase it's that

Comment: Can you post the path to your `404.php` relative to document root?

Comment: 404.php is in the same directory as index.php, if that's what you mean

Comment: Uncomment `#ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`, i.e. remove the leading `#` from that line

Comment: done and added an extra comment above, if commented # ErrorDocument 500 line, then 404 ones only shows 500 errors

Comment: @JenStar23, so based on your original question with `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.php`, you were not getting 500 error codes?

Comment: i was i just was tricking the server aka ErrorDocument 500 http://ww.example.com/404.php sorry about that, edited that above now btw